# Firebase firestore - use collectionGroup queries in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to use `collectionGroup` queries in a cloud function, and it only appears to be available if I import from firebase/app:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
const db = firebase.firestore();

...
const snap = await db.collectionGroup('comments').where('foo', '==', 'bar').get();
```

But when I try to deploy I get

> TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function

In my other cloud functions, I have always imported from firebase-admin, but typescript tells me it has no `collectionGroup` method.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const db = admin.firestore();
```

Currently my versions are sitting at the following which should be latest:

```
"firebase": "^6.2.4",
"firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
```

It would also be nice to understand why you would get your `db` instance from 'firebase-admin' or 'firebase/app'. I don't understand why there are 2 separate instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
const db = admin.firestore()

const snap = db.collectionGroup('comments').where('foo', '==', 'bar').get()
```

The `collectionGroup` type is supported on the [last version](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/types/firestore.d.ts#L160)

I would recommend to delete `node_modules` and install again (I just sanity check your sample and it went good, no issues on `"firebase-admin": "8.0.0"`).

Comment: Thanks! VScode cached the interface from the older version. It wasn't until I option clicked through to the class that it refreshed the interface.